# Copy conditonal format colour from range of cells to another range of cells

Tags: vba

I have used the conditional formatting colour scale on a range of cells (BY11:CV20). I would like to copy the colour format of these cells to another range (AC11:AZ20). I only require the cell background colour to be copied and pasted. My workbook name is Cars and my sheet name is Channels. I am new to VBA and have tried different coding but nothing works. Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the formatting then delete the newly created Conditional Format rule

1. Copy the original cell range R1
2. Select the destination cell range R2
3. Home tab > Paste drop down > Paste Special... > Paste-Formats
4. Home tab > Conditional Formatting drop down > Manage Rules > set 'Show formatting     rules for:' to 'This Worksheet' > Select data range for R2 (should be at the bottom) > delete rule

Comment: I do not want to apply the conditional format to the second range as the data is completely different. I only require the colour of the cells in the range BY11: CV20 to be copied to the range AC11:AZ20

Comment: answer updated to match